# sendRedirect на предыдущую страницу при смене языка

Tags: java, локализация

Проблема в следующем - хочу сделать мультиязычное Java web-приложение, чтобы во всех страницах приложения была возможность переключаться между языками. 
Для возврата на ту страницу, откуда пользователь вызвал смену языка делаю:

```
String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("referer", referer);
response.sendRedirect(referer);
```

Но, когда я авторизовался юзером (`method POST`) и пытаюсь сделать смена языка мне выскакивает `exception`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где искать ошибку?

Comment: Больше кода дайте

Answer (score 0):

У тебя ошибка, обозначающая отсутствие необходимого обекта `Command`.
На самом деле i18n можно разраулить на стороне клиента, на jsp странице.
Скорее всего, рещение твоей проблемы находится [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276061/how-to-internationalize-a-java-web-application).

Comment: Да, у меня пустая команда, так как сама команда передается в теле (метод POST), если GET, то работает все хорошо.

Comment: Попробуй сделать так, как на ссылке, что я оставил. У меня так сработало. + при данной реализации тебе не надо будет обращаться к серверной части.

Comment: Да, но так как передаю при помощи POST, то сама команда передается в теле, подскажите как вытащить команду из страницы которой перешел? С методом GET работает sendredirect правильно, но я хочу, чтобы работала ситуация, когда пользователь вводит логин и пароль (работает метод POST), то он переходит в личный кабинет, а потом я нажимаю кнопку смена языка. И как я понимаю мне нужно повторить команду авторизация, но имя команды зашито в методе POST

Comment: Для смены языка ты используешь кнопки, при нажатии на которые менятеся язык ui?

Comment: я использую отдельную команду для смены языка как и все команды она работает через единый контроллер. Ситуация следующая: загрузилась главная страница с формой логин и пароль, с локалью юзера. Далее юзер вводит логин и пароль и нажимает кнопку войти (метод POST), появляется личный кабинет. Потом нажимает кнопку другого языка(например английский) происходит запрос 
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Controller?command=localization&local=en"></a>
через сервлет контроллер попадает в команду localization:

Comment: public class Localization implements Command {
 @Override
 public void execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  String local = request.getParameter("local");
  request.getSession(true).setAttribute("local", local);
String referer = request.getHeader("Referer");
  String command = request.getParameter("command");
  request.getSession(true).setAttribute("referer", referer);
   response.sendRedirect(referer);
 }
}
который вроде бы должен по коду выполнить предыдущий запрос, но с новым языком.

Comment: который вроде бы должен по коду выполнить предыдущий запрос, но с новым языком. Для Get проходит, а для пост выскакивает exception как на скрине выше.

Comment: А вообще если ты разрабатываешь Single Page Application (SPA), ты не должен перезагружать страницу каждый раз, когда меняется язык. Лучше всего сделать это с помощью property файлов и библиотеки `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>` на стороне клиента, без обращения к серверу.

Comment: Ты же пытаешься сделать `request.getParameter("command")`, т.е. взять имя твоей команды из запроса. Так работает GET. Для того, что бы так сработал POST, я бы сделал так `<form method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="language" value="YOUR_LOCALE"} /></form>` А внутри самой формы вставь ссылку, которая сделает форме submit.